# Do I need to do the checkin in the Thalys?

Tags: trains, check-in, thalys

I am going to use the Thalys from Paris to Brussels.
Its the first time I use it and the whole booking process resembles a lot using an airplane, which leads me to questions.

Do you need to do some sort of (on-line) check in? 
What do you need to travel? printing the e-ticket is enough?

Comment: Note that if you've bought your Thalys ticket as part of a flight (eg as a TGVAir or with KLM), then there are additional restrictions, mostly around ensuring you do actually take the train before/after the flight

Answer (score 6):

Printing the e-ticket is enough, it should already mention your seat number like any train ticket with a seat reservation. One difference with most other high-speed trains is that there will be a train attendant at each door, who will scan your ticket before you board the train. You probably need to show some photo ID as well, although they usually didn't look at it very carefully when I used the Thalys in the past.

Media reports also suggest that an airport-like bag inspection has been or will be introduced following the last terror attacks in Paris but I have not used the Thalys in the last couple of weeks so I cannot report on that yet.